# Python3 xlib: Failed to parse Xauthority

Tags: python-3.x, xorg

As a minimal example, the following code:

```
from Xlib import xauth
xauth.Xauthority()
```

gives the following output:

```
Xlib.xauth: warning, failed to parse part of xauthority file /home/sam-barr/.Xauthority, aborting all further parsing
```

Python xlib version: 0.27

xorg-xauth version: 1.1

OS: (arch) linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to delete my .Xauthority file and then reboot.